# Copying file from one directory to another directory in google colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

my directory structure in google Colab is  following :
under the directory  `'/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/dogs_cats/train'` there  are images of cats and dogs, those are numbered as follow : cat.0, cat.1 and so on(the same  for dogs), i would like to write python codes  which will takes some portions of images  of cats and dogs  for train, test and validation folders, for instance  destination folder for train folders for cat is follow

```
'/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/Dogs_cats/train/cats'
```

this folder is empty and i want to copy first 1000 picture of cat(in total i have 25000 image, 12500 for cat and 12500 for dog), so i wrote   following code from well know deep learning book

```
fnames = ['cat.{}.jpg'.format(i) for i in range(1000)]
for fname in fnames:
    src = os.path.join('/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/dogs_cats/train', fname)
    dst = os.path.join('/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/Dogs_cats/train/cats', fname)
    shutil.copyfile(src, dst)
```

idea is very simple : first we create list of  cats names(cat.0.jpg,cat.1.jpg and so on, after that we  we connected file name to the source and destination and  we copied file using shutil library, the code runs without error, but there is no result(i checked destination folder several times), so what is the problem? please help me

Comment: if you try os.listdir('/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/dogs_cats/train'), do you see the files ?

Comment: yes yes it works now, i think it  needed some tim